# How can I create a backup of a SQL Server table with a CREATE AS?

Tags: sql-server

I would like to backup my data1 table. What I did was to try this:

```
CREATE TABLE data1Backup AS SELECT * FROM data1
```

but it seems this does not work.  Can someone tell me what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select *
INTO data1Backup
From data1
```

This will create a new table named 'data1Backup' with the same schema as 'data1' and will contain all the data in 'data1'. This will fail though if 'data1Backup' already exists so you might want to add some code to drop the table first, if it exists.

Answer (score -1):

`CREATE` does not back up or copy tables. `CREATE` creates tables.

You can use `select into` to create a copy of your table:

```
select * 
into data1Backup 
from data1
```

This will work so long as data1backup does not already exist. If it does, use this instead to insert into the existing table (if it already has data in it, you may want to empty it first with a `delete` or `truncate`):

```
insert into data1Backup 
select * from data1
```

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain what they feel could be improved with this answer?